# I'm encountering a syntax error while plotting vectors

Tags: python, numpy, syntax-error

Here are my codes for plotting some vectors:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
epsilon_new = 10e-16;
a1 = np.array([1,1])
a2 = np.array([-1,1])
b1 = np.array([1,1])
b2 = np.array([1-epsilon_new,1])

c1 =4;
c2 = 2; #coefficients solved using basis A
c3 = 6-(4/epsilon_new);
c4 = 4/epsilon_new ; #coefficients solved using basis B
f = np.array([2,6]) #true f

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.array([0,f[0]]),np.array([0,f[1]]),label='true f vector');
plt.plot(np.array([0,c1*a1[0]+c2*a2[0]),np.array([0,c1*a1[1]+c2*a2[1]),linestyle='--',label='f vector basis A');
```

I keep getting a syntax error in the very last line:

```
plt.plot(np.array([0,c1*a1[0]+c2*a2[0]),np.array([0,c1*a1[1]+c2*a2[1]),linestyle='--',label='f vector basis A');
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So what I was trying to do is to plot the vector [2 6], then plot the very same vector using another set of basis vector A, where a1 is the first column of that 2x2 matrix and a2 is the second column of that 2x2 matrix. I can't figure out why there is a syntax error

Comment: you are missing a `]` see here `np.array([0,c1*a1[0]+c2*a2[0]),` And same problem here as well `np.array([0,c1*a1[1]+c2*a2[1])`

Comment: whenever you get a syntax error with a ^, look for the previous function or line. It is always the previous one that causes the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has two missing `]`

```
plt.plot(np.array([0,c1*a1[0]+c2*a2[0]),np.array([0,c1*a1[1]+c2*a2[1]),linestyle='--',label='f vector basis A');
```

The errors are here:

```
np.array([0,c1*a1[0]+c2*a2[0])  #missing ]. It should be a2[0]])
```

and here:

```
np.array([0,c1*a1[1]+c2*a2[1])  #missing ]. It should be a2[1]])
```

Comment: thx a lot! I get too dizzy after using [ ] for indexing lol